# python change a files creation and modification time without having to use a subcommand?

Tags: python, date, time, touch, concurrentmodification

I want to change the modification and creation time of any file with python. This would be the command I use in Linux:

```
touch -a -m -t 201512180130.09 ./file.jpg
```

Then I check the following I can see the date is changed correctly:

```
$ls -l --time-style=full-iso
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 44570 2015-12-18 01:30:09.000000000 -0500 file.jpg

$exiftool ./file.jpg | grep -i date
File Modification Date/Time     : 2015:12:18 01:30:09-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2015:12:18 01:30:09-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2022:12:13 19:39:43-05:00
```

I tried using the `Pathlib('./file.jpg').touch()` and `os.utime('./file.jpg', None)`. neither worked.
How can I do this in Python without having to use os or subprocess commands?